# The solution set of an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The solution set of the inequality $0 < |x-1| < r$ consists of ...

What is the answer to this question? When solving it, I get the following solutions:

$x>1$ and $x<1$

$x<r+1$ and $x>r+1$

But the solution is apparently

$(1-r,1)\cup(1,1+r)$

How is it this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,
$$
|x-1|<r\;\iff\; -r <x-1<r\; \iff\; 1-r<x<1+r.
$$
That is, every $x\in (1-r,1+r)$ satisfies $|x-1|<r$. Now remove from this set, the point(s) that do not satisfy the condition $|x-1|>0$, i.e. the point(s) satisfying $|x-1|=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x<1$ you have :

$0 < |x-1| < r\Rightarrow 0<1-x<r\Rightarrow 0>x-1>-r\Rightarrow 1>x>1-r$

For $x>1$ you have :

$0 < |x-1| < r\Rightarrow 0<x-1<r\Rightarrow  1<x<1+r$

So, your solution set is.. ???